# Is it possible to use DBeaver and the DuckDB connector to read parquet files directly from Azure Datalake Storage?

Tags: azure-data-lake, dbeaver, azure-data-lake-gen2, duckdb

I've used DBeaver and the DuckDB database connection (Path = `:memeory:`) to read local `.parquet` files.

`SELECT * FROM "C:\folder\myfile.parquet"`

Is it possible to read `.parquet` files direct from ADLS?

I've tried the following: `SELECT * FROM "abfs://continer@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/folder/my.parquet"` but that doesn't work

If possible, could someone please provide an example connection/path string?

**Update**
It is possible, please follow the below example:

```
INSTALL azure;
LOAD azure;

SET azure_storage_connection_string = '<connection string from storage account/access keys/connection string>';

SELECT * FROM 'azure://<continer>/<folder>/<filename>.parquet' limit 10;
```

Comment: How you are connecting Dbeaver to Gen2? Can you provide the approach that you are trying with Duck db connector?

Comment: That maybe the issue, I'm not 'connecting' to Gen2.

The only thing I'm providing to the Duckdb connector is Path = `:memeory:`.

I was then hoping to connect to Gen2 by providing a path/URL in the SELECT statement.  This approach work for reading local files, was hoping somthing similar would work for Gen 2.

How should I try to connect to Gen 2?

Comment: For those that stumble across this, I later found out it is possible:

`INSTALL azure;`
`LOAD azure;`

`SET azure_storage_connection_string = '<connection string from storage account/access keys/connection string>';`

`SELECT * FROM 'azure://<continer>/<folder>/<filename>.parquet' limit 10;`

Comment: You can post this as answer itself instead of editing the question. This will be helpful to everyone who visits this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, please follow the below example:

```
INSTALL azure;
LOAD azure;

SET azure_storage_connection_string = '<connection string from storage account/access keys/connection string>';

SELECT * FROM 'azure://<continer>/<folder>/<filename>.parquet' limit 10;
```